# Prevent iOS from displaying Call or Tethering Bar

Tags: ios, iphone, statusbar

I know it is possible to completely hide the status bar in iOS applications.

Is there a way to allow the regular slim status bar but prevent iOS from displaying the larger in-call or tethering bars?

Both programmatic solutions and solutions using the app's Info.plist are fine. Unfortunately, resizing the view or using auto-layout is not an option in the specific application.